# How to set MATLAB R2015a as the default program for opening mfiles?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, matlab, default-settings, mathematica

I have `Mathematica 10.2` and `MATLAB R2015a` installed on my computer and unfortunately MATLAB m-files are recognized as Mathematica notebooks by the window.
When I right-click on an m-file and choose `open with`, there's no option for MATLAB.
And if I use the option `choose default program...` from that context menu, click on `Browse` and go through the following path:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\bin\matlab.exe
```

It won't be added to the context menu. What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you tick "Always use this program"?

Comment: @AFH yes i did it

Comment: I can't be sure that W7 was the same, but on W10, if you right-click one of the files you want to link then select **Properties**, the **General** tab shows the program which opens it with a **Change** button alongside: this will allow you to select the default program.

Comment: @AFH yes, there is [such option](https://goo.gl/uvXzd1) in win7, too but as you see in the picture, MATLAB is not listed and if I click the `Browse` button and go through the path that I mentioned above to `matlab.exe`, it won't be added to the list and I cannot choose it

Comment: That is very strange. All I can suggest is to run `explorer` as administrator or to make sure that your internet security software has not locked your settings.

Comment: @AFH windows explorer? how can I find out if the internet security software has blocked the settings? I use `Microsoft Security Essentials`

Comment: I have not used MSE much, and I no longer have a system running it, but I would suggest you check the logs first, to see if there were any entries associated with your attempted change. If running `explorer` as administrator doesn't work and you can't find anything in MSE, then you may have to resort to `regedit`, but I don't recommend this if you've never used it before: the modifications necessary will depend on existing entries, so it will be difficult to give guidance, and mistakes could damage your system.

Comment: @AFH I've edited my question. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: Try the following commands in a `cmd` shell: `FTYPE matlabfile="C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\bin\matlab.exe" "%1"` followed by `ASSOC .m=matlabfile`. You should then be able to double-click a `.m` file and open it in matlab.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks for that comment: I knew about these commands, but I thought their scope was limited to typing file names in `cmd` shells. When I experimented I got errors if `cmd` was not run as administrator, but the associations then worked in `explorer`. It would be a good idea to type `assoc .m` first, so that the original association can be verified as `.m=m-file`, allowing it to be restored in the future if necessary.

Comment: @DavidPostill ok, it's fixed. in fact when I run the `cmd` as administrator and typed what you said `matlab` will be listed in the `open with` window and I can change the default program

Comment: @AFH see my last comment

Comment: @sepideh Great. I will add an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How Can I set MATLAB as the default program for opening `.m` files?

You need to run the following commands **as an Administrator** in a `cmd` shell:

```
assoc .m
```

Run this first, so that the original association can be verified as `.m=m-file`, allowing it to be restored in the future if necessary.

Then run:

```
ftype matlabfile="C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\bin\matlab.exe" "%1" 
assoc .m=matlabfile
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [assoc](http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) - Display or change the association between a file extension and a fileType
- [ftype](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) - Display or change the link between a FileType and an executable program.